# I am unable to create a logic

Tags: sql, ms-access

Display the detail of the customer who have contributed the maximum amount of charges to through all of their parcel delivery orders

I have one customer table:
Customer
CustomerId CustomerName CustomerAddress

Another business
BusinessId Name charges CustomerId

A customer might have many charges, and we need to sum every customer charge, find the maximum of those sumed charges and display who have paid higest charge

```
SELECT  customerid,
    MAX(scharge) 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT 
        customerid, SUM(charges) as scharge 
    FROM parcel
    group by customerid
)
group by customerid
```

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with current attempt. On the face, it appears to answer your question. Did you need all customer details to appear with *customerid*?

Answer (score 0):

Use `TOP` and `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 c.*
FROM (SELECT customerid, SUM(charges) as scharge 
      FROM parcel
      GROUP BY customerid
     ) c
ORDER BY scharge DESC;
```